# How to upload Multiple Images to firebase and get the URL in separate childs just am getting all the URL in one child value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String key;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private FirebaseStorage mStorageRef;
    private Button mButton;
    private StorageTask mUploadTask;
    private List<Uri> uploadedImages = new ArrayList<>();

    private DatabaseReference mRefre;
    ArrayList<String> filepath = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hhhh);

        mRefre = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addphoto);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                filepath.clear();

                FilePickerBuilder.getInstance().setMaxCount(3)
                        .setSelectedFiles(filepath)
                        .setActivityTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
                        .pickPhoto(MainActivity.this);    
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {

            case FilePickerConst.REQUEST_CODE:

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

                    final ArrayList<String> filepath;
                    filepath = data.getStringArrayListExtra(FilePickerConst.KEY_SELECTED_PHOTOS);

                    filepath.add("image1");
                    filepath.add("image2");

                    for (String path : filepath) {

                        final Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
                        key = mRefre.child("products").push().getKey();

                        StorageReference photoRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Images").child(uploadedImages + file.getLastPathSegment());

                        mUploadTask = photoRef.putFile(file);
                        mUploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                                uploadedImages.add(downloadUrl);

                                HashMap userMap = new HashMap();
                                userMap.put("image1",uploadedImages.toString());
                                userMap.put("image2",uploadedImages.toString());
                                mRefre.child("product-images").setValue(userMap);
                            }
                        });    
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I am doing firebase project and trying to upload multiple images using imagepicker with a maximum of 3 images. The images are successfully uploaded to firebase storage but when I try to get the URL it saves the 3 images in one child Value. I am trying to save it in separate values and name them so I can retrieve them later.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: you need to modify this part:
 userMap.put("image1",uploadedImages.toString());
 userMap.put("image2",uploadedImages.toString());
 mRefre.child("product-images").setValue(userMap); 
in the way you want the values to be saved in FirebaseDB

Comment: What does it mean, "it saves the 3 images in one child Value"? Give me an example.

Comment: Alex Mamo You can see my code its downloading the image Uri 3x in Child Image1 and child image2 i want to rename the selected images and save them as child and value the image url do you have solution

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a different approach: instead of looping, use the built in Promise/`Task` construct. This is detailed: https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/d4f1327b58ad69334ef06327184df790 or [How to upload multiple files to Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673499/how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-firebase) and [Android Firebase multiple image upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178298/android-firebase-multiple-image-upload)

Comment: same its butting urls in one child and i cant retrieve them